# Error 'Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

```js
db.collection(USERDETAILS_COLLECTION).findOneAndUpdate({
    "emailVerificationHistory.verifyCode": mailCode
  }, {
    '$pull': {
      "emailVerificationHistory.$.verifyCode": mailCode
    }
  },
  function(err, pullData) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send({
        msg: 'User Verified Succesfully',
        status: 1
      });
    }
  });
```

When I execute the above code, I am getting the following error.

```
name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value',
  code: 16837,
```

Below is my MongoDB object.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593270b8bc98ea235cfaf68f"),
    "username" : "parengalhisham@gmail.com",
    "roleId" : 3,
    "userId" : ObjectId("593270b8bc98ea235cfaf68e"),
    "profile" : {
        "firstName" : "Hisham",
        "lastName" : "Mubarak"
    },
    "activeFlag" : 1,
    "authType" : [ 
        "facebook"
    ],
    "emailVerified" : false,
    "emailVerificationHistory" : [ 
        {
            "email" : "parengalhisham@gmail.com",
            "verifyCode" : "59327155480b791b7845dfd7",
            "requestDate" : ISODate("2017-06-03T08:20:37.156Z"),
            "verifiedDate" : ISODate("2017-06-03T10:31:53.720Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I search through the emailVerificationHistory array using verifyCode and remove the verifyCode only from that first object inside array? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your usage of [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) is incorrect:

```
db.collection(USERDETAILS_COLLECTION).findOneAndUpdate(
  { "emailVerificationHistory.verifyCode":mailCode },
  {'$pull':{ "emailVerificationHistory": { "verifyCode": mailCode } },
  function(err,pullData) {
      if(err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          res.send({msg: 'User Verified Succesfully', status: 1});
      }
  }
);
```

The [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) update operator works like a query in itself. So it takes a condition and "pulls" the matching elements from the array.

So whilst it is good practice to use a selection query to match the element in the array, you don't use the positional `$` operator to the element, but rather supply the array itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Changing the `$pull` to `$unset` helped me get what I wanted.

Comment: @HishamMubarak Actually `$unset` will only "replace" the array element with `null`. If you need to remove it then you actually use `$pull`. If you wanted to remove "only one of many matches" then you `$unset` and then `$pull` as two operations. However your value should be "unique" so you should be using `$pull`.